# Replace certain part of the string at random

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

The problem:
There is a string with conditions and I want to replace an operator with other operator at random.

The possible solution:

```
import re
import random

s = 'operand1 > 273 and operand2 < 459 or operand3 == 42 and operand4 < 100'

# create list of operators with random replacement
repl = random.choice(['<','>','==','!='])
operators = re.findall(r'[<>]|==|!=', s)
operators[random.choice(range(len(operators)))] = repl

# create list of other parts of the string
the_rest = re.split(r'[<>]|==|!=', s)

# recombine a string
s_new = the_rest[0]
for operator, operand in zip(operators, the_rest[1:]):
    s_new += operator + operand
print(s_new)
```

It seems a little vague. Could you offer a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter, we could easily change the list and patterns.

Comment: you want all occurrences of the operator to be replaced? also, you want the replacement to be an operator which is not present in `s`?

Comment: No, just only one operator in 's' at random. In my example I need to replace ('>' or '<' or '==' or '<'). The 's' could contain random set of operators, but all possible operators are defined a priory. So yes, replacement could be any operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much simpler with `re.sub()` function (with callback *replacement* function called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*):

```
import random, re

s = 'operand1 > 273 and operand2 < 459 or operand3 == 42 and operand4 < 100'
operators = ['<','>','==','!=']
s_new = re.sub(r'[<>]|==|!=', lambda op: random.choice(operators), s)

print(s_new)
```

An exemplary output:

```
operand1 != 273 and operand2 == 459 or operand3 > 42 and operand4 == 100
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.sub

Comment: Good! But I want to replace only one of the operators, not all. It seems that we need adjust a little bit lambda: lambda op: op.group() if random.random() < X else random.choice(operators), where X is a probability of change exactly one of the operators. Many thanks for this solution!

Comment: @Roman I think this is not what OP is looking for.
<br/>
ip: `operand1 > 273 and operand2 < 459 or operand3 == 42 and operand4 < 100` 

op: `operand1 == 273 and operand2 == 459 or operand3 > 42 and operand4 < 100` 
in this example, it replaced `>` with `==` and `==` with `>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
s = 'operand1 > 273 and operand2 < 459 or operand3 == 42 and operand4 < 100'
operators = ['<', '>', '==', '!=']

print(" ".join([random.choice(operators) if x in operators else x for x in s.split()]))
```

Edit 1. Well the assumption I made that the OP wanted all the operators replaced was wrong.

`s.split()` makes a list out of the string words, excludes spaces.

A list is created from the original string with an operator chosen at random to replace any given operator in it.

`" ".join` turns the list to a new string including spaces in between the lists elements.

Edit 2. I came back to it during my coffee break. This changes one operator.

```
import random

s = 'operand1 > 273 and operand2 < 459 or operand3 == 42 and operand4 < 100'
print(s)
operators = ['<', '>', '==', '!=']

# make a list out of the string words
s_split = s.split()

# make a list of tuples (position, operator) form the list containg the string words
occurances = [(idx, x) for idx, x in enumerate(s_split) if x in operators]

# pick a random operator form the list to change
occurance_to_change = random.choice(occurances)

# pick a random operator to replace the one in the sentence and make sure they are different
operator_to_place = random.choice(operators)
while operator_to_place == occurance_to_change[1]:
    operator_to_place = random.choice(operators)

# replace the operator
s_split[occurance_to_change[0]] = operator_to_place

# put the resulting list back together to form a string
s_result = " ".join(s_split)
print(s_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace random occurrence of an operator chosen randomly with a different operator chosen at random

```
import random

# returns a random operator
def ran(): 
    repl = random.choice(['<','>','==','!='])
    return repl

# replaces cth occurrence of a with b in str
def ran_repl(str, a, b, c): 
    ls = [i for i in range(len(str) - len(a)+1) if str[i:i+len(a)]==a]
    str = list(str)
    str[ls[c-1]:ls[c-1]+len(a)] = b
    return ''.join(str)

s = 'operand1 > 273 and operand2 < 459 or operand3 == 42 and operand4 < 100'
print(s)

x = ran()
while x not in s:
    x = ran()

y = ran()
while y == x:
    y = ran()

l = s.count(x)
# if multiple occurrence of x in s, replace a random occurrence
if l > 1:
    n = random.randint(1,l)
    s = ran_repl(s,x,y,n)
else:
    s = s.replace(x,y)
print(s)
```

Output

```
operand1 > 273 and operand2 < 459 or operand3 == 42 and operand4 < 100
operand1 > 273 and operand2 < 459 or operand3 == 42 and operand4 == 100
```